# Getting a syntax error in Sessions#controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use the same code that I used in rails 3 for sessions.

```
 def create
   user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])

   if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
     session[:user_id] = user.id    #stores the id in the session
     redirect_to user       #displays the user/show view
   else             
     flash.now[:error] = "Invalid name/password combination."
     render 'new'                   
   end
 end
```

I have adjusted it to

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])

  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id #stores the id in the session 
    redirect_to user #displays the user/show view
  else              
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid name/password combination."
    render 'new' #shows the signin page again 
  end
end
```

But I am now getting the error:

```
"SyntaxError in SessionsController#new" 
 /sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...te(params[:password]) session[:user_id] = user.id
```

I'm sure it is to do with the fact I am using rails 4 now and not 3 and there is some syntax that is not compatible with 4, but I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: I believe this is because your code formatting is awful. Insert a carriage return between `if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])` and `session[:user_id] = user.id`.

Comment: I improved the format of your question. Also I think I fixed the error :) Next time try to make a better format for your code so we can understand.

Comment: @radubogdan please in the future avoid attempts to improve anything but formatting.

Comment: @mudasobwa Agree. Still, he doesn't need to agree with my changes.

Comment: @radubogdan  The point is that now the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @mudasobwa totally get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the body of an if statement on the same line as the condition unless you separate it from the condition with the keyword `then`. Here I have tidied your code, so there is a line break after the condition.

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_username(params[:username]) 

  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id # stores the id in the session
                                # displays the user/show view
  else             
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid name/password combination." # Shows the sign in page again 
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, resolved - apologies about my messy code!